# Error while executing symbolicatecrash command "Can't exec "/usr/bin/xcode-select": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash"

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

My application get crash in apple's testing phase. I have crash log. When I am execute symbolicatecrash command, I get an error

Can't exec "/usr/bin/xcode-select": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/symbolicatecrash

or some how command get executed then it shows same crash file.

My .app & .dSYM files are in same directory.

I don't know what is problem. kindly help me in solving above issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

xcode-select is missing from /usr/bin. Try installing XCode again, and making sure you choose to install the optional Unix support and the Developer Tools System.

xcode-select is a program which should be in usr/bin that manages the path to XCode if you have multiple XCode versions installed. Versions of tools such as xcodebuild in /usr/bin are just shims that redirect to which ever version of XCode you are choosing to use.

See this Apple [link](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/XcodeCoexistence/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Details/Details.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006599-CH6-SW15) and this [man page](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcode-select.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/xcode-select). In particular, note this: "When writing software that uses the Xcode UNIX tools, Apple recommends using the copy of those tools installed in Xcode/usr instead of /usr, because your users may not have tools in /usr if they have disabled the optional UNIX Development Support choice in the Xcode installer. Your software can find the path to the  directory with the xcode-select command (see previous section)."

Comment: Err, can you clarify "/usr vs /usr"?  One of those must be wrong.

Comment: Done. I'd written <Xcode>/usr and it didn't show up! (Let's see if it does in a comment.)